# Logging in Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Dash application and I am trying to get proper logging in place. So for that I am trying to implement that after every request my log handler captures the following things (please suggest best practices if I missed any):

- Time
- Type of the request method (Get/post)
- The path requested
- Request referrer
- Request agent
- Selected inputs and flags from the front end
- Response status
- Response content_length
- If I can capture the time between the request and response

Is there a way to capture this? I tried looking but couldn't find out many things that I can log.

So far the code I have is the following -

```py
@dash_server.after_request
def after_request(response):
    """ Logging after every request. """
    logger = logging.getLogger("app.access")
    logger.info("%s [%s] %s %s %s %s %s %s %s",
                dt.utcnow().strftime("%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3],
                dash.callback_context.triggered,
                dash.callback_context.inputs,
                response.status,
                response.content_length)
    return response
```

I am not sure how to capture the rest and I couldn't find a guide to perform this action.

Comment: Is your app deployed on some server? You can create logs from server side.

Comment: @marcin yes AWS EC2 using Gunicorn. How do you propose doing that?

Comment: I am using IIS server and its logging module. My suggestion is to check whether it is possible to use your server built in logging, e.g. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html